# Sublime-edit Multiedit only in selected text

Tags: sublime-text-3

Like many people I find the multiple edit features of SublimeEdit amazing.

However sometimes I only want to do multiple edit in a certain area.

Is there a simple way I can Select a block of text say a single function then select a word and hit `Alt-F3` to multi edit the function.  At the moment if i do this it selects in the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `Selection -> Split into Lines`. Under OSX, that's bound to <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>.